# How can I keep a button that's on the left of a search field under it when the size is reduced?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There may be a very simple solution to this but I have no idea how to put it into words. I'm trying to get a minus button to go under an element when the screen size is reduced but it just follows the natural order.

[image]

And when the screen get's smaller.

[image]

Is there any way to get the minus button on bottom when the screen size is on a mobile device for example?

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Boarded</label>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-number btn-lg btn-block"
                                    (click)="decreaseBoardedValueClicked()">-</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
                                    class="form-control form-control-lg input-group-text" name="boarded" min="0"
                                    [(ngModel)]="log.boarded" #logBoarded="ngModel" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number btn-lg btn-block"
                                    (click)="increaseBoardedValueClicked()">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.required && logBoarded.touched">
                            The number of passengers boarded is required.
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.pattern && logBoarded.touched">
                            Invalid input. It can only contain counting numbers.
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap do you use in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `bootstrap v4` then you should use `bootstrap order classes` for maintaining the order of your elements. Here is the live demo to your question also look into [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrtnoy93/3/)

[Reordering Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Boarded</label>
  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" class="form-control form-control-lg input-group-text" name="boarded" min="0" [(ngModel)]="log.boarded" #logBoarded="ngModel" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number btn-lg btn-block" (click)="increaseBoardedValueClicked()">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 order-md-first">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-number btn-lg btn-block" (click)="decreaseBoardedValueClicked()">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.required && logBoarded.touched">
    The number of passengers boarded is required.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.pattern && logBoarded.touched">
    Invalid input. It can only contain counting numbers.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

added `col-sm-12 col-md-5` classes to buttons and `col-sm-12 col-md-2` classes to textbox. hope this helps thanks

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .form-row :nth-child(1){order:2}
  .form-row :nth-child(2){order:1}
  .form-row :nth-child(3){order:3}
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-row :nth-child(1){order:1}
  .form-row :nth-child(2){order:2}
  .form-row :nth-child(3){order:3}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Boarded</label>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-number btn-lg btn-block"
                                    (click)="decreaseBoardedValueClicked()">-</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"
                                    class="form-control form-control-lg input-group-text" name="boarded" min="0"
                                    [(ngModel)]="log.boarded" #logBoarded="ngModel" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number btn-lg btn-block"
                                    (click)="increaseBoardedValueClicked()">+</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.required && logBoarded.touched">
                            The number of passengers boarded is required.
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="logBoarded.errors?.pattern && logBoarded.touched">
                            Invalid input. It can only contain counting numbers.
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Okay I tried that but the minus button is still on top when logically, it should be on bottom. Thank you so much though. I actually finally understand what the sm and md are for now.

Comment: 1st will be textbox, 2nd will be minus button and 3rd will be plus button.. is this how you want it??

Comment: i have updated my ans. please check.. i will add description if this is what you are looking for. thanks